# Reading fixed-width column text file with multiple different types in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, flat-file, fixed-width

I would like to read text file with fixed-width column size (read_fwf) using pandas. Though each line in the file can be of different type (each would represent different structure with different number of columns) determined by the first character on the line. How to parse into (I would say multiple) dataFrames depending on type? Is there a parameter of read_fwf which can handle this?

File Example. Record types A,B,C:

```
Header
A1234  Another Field 567 fourthfield
A32    Second Field  456 fourthfield2
BFirstColumn   SecondColumn  ThirdColumn
BFirstColumn2  SecondColumn2 ThirdColumn2
CA  B  C  123  456  789
CEF TTTCCC001  001  001
A1     Next Field    999 fourthfield3
```

I tried to split based on the first column by reading:

```
data = pd.read_fwf(path, widths=[1,...], header=0, skipfooter=0, names = ['Type','Data'])
As = data.loc[data['Type'] == 'A']
```

But then I did not find a way how to easily break fixed-with data inside the pandas dataframe As['Data']. You cannot input pandas dataframe into read_fwf so you can only do.

```
As['col001'] = As['Data'].str.slice(0,6)
As['col002'] = As['Data'].str.slice(6,10)
...
```

Is there any simplier way?

Comment: If you don't find a library that can handle this, you can try creating your own :). I have done the same for R by creating a [function](https://github.com/prontog/multifwf) that splits a file by record-type then calls *read.fwf* for each new file. If you are interested you can find more info on this [post](https://prontog.wordpress.com/2016/01/27/reading-a-file-with-lines-of-different-fixed-width-formats/).

Comment: Yes, I'll probably have to do something like that. I didn't find a library which can handle that so far, though in my industry it's quite common situation. Shouldn't be difficult to filter based on beginning of the line.